# passing data through segues

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use one web view and have three different buttons to take you to this web view. Each one will take you to a different website. I've created a new webview class and in this class I have a method to set which url it will go to.

In the original view controller I'm trying to send a different number through to this method but it says there is no known instance method.

The code is below:

method to set url

```
-(void)setUrlNo:(int)urlNo
{

    if (urlNo == 0) {

        url = @"http://www.twitter.com/ac3112";
    } else if (urlNo == 1) {
        url = @"http://www.facebook.com/ac3112";
    } else if (urlNo == 2) {
        url = @"http://www.adamcarlin.co.uk";

    }
}
```

prepare for segue method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Twitter"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setUrlNo:1];

    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FB"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setUrlNo:2];
    } else {
        [segue.destinationViewController setUrlNo:3];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`segue.destinationViewController` returns an object of type `id`. You'll need to cast it to your view controller type to send the message without warning:

```
[(YourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setUrlNo:1];
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to have solved the problem. Any other ideas? or am i just doing it wrong?

Comment: Is `-(void)setUrlNo:(int)urlNo` method exposed in your destination view controller's header?

Comment: its never mentioned in the header file

Comment: Fixed that problem. Forgot to declare the procedure in the header file. Can you tell im a begineer? Next problem is the UIWebView it leads to is just showing black.

Comment: How/where are you doing your `loadRequest:`?

Answer (score 0):

to open a different website and send url through segue you could use this method based on a master view controller. You create a push segue from each table cell or button and drag to UIViewController and then put the segue value from the below in there to make sure you're getting the right site/value.

FollowViewController.h

```
@interface FollowViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

FollowViewController.m segue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     FollowDetailViewController *webController = [[FollowDetailViewController alloc] init];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Facebook"]) { // Facebook
    NSString *urlstr=@"https://www.facebook.com/";
    webController = [segue destinationViewController];
    webController.urlstr = urlstr;
    webController.title = @"Facebook"; // this sets the title of the next page

    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Instagram"]) { // Instagram
    NSString *urlstr=@"http://instagram.com/";
    webController = [segue destinationViewController];
    webController.urlstr = urlstr;
    webController.title = @"Instagram"; // this sets the title of the next page
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Twitter"]) { // Twitter
    NSString *urlstr=@"https://twitter.com/";
    webController = [segue destinationViewController];
    webController.urlstr = urlstr;
    webController.title = @"Twitter"; // this sets the title of the next page
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YouTube"]) { // YouTube
    NSString *urlstr=@"http://www.youtube.com/";
    webController = [segue destinationViewController];
    webController.urlstr = urlstr;
    webController.title = @"YouTube"; // this sets the title of the next page
    }
    self.title = @"Follow"; // This sets the title of the back button, and the title of this page
}
```

FollowDetailViewController.h

```
@interface FollowDetailViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *urlstr;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlstr;

@end
```

FollowDetailViewController.m

```
@implementation FollowDetailViewController

@synthesize WebView;
@synthesize urlstr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.WebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

good luck!